# Why does XCode show the wrong object address in the debugger window?

Tags: iphone, xcode

My application tested whether my selectedViewController was equal to my moreNavigationController.

```
if( self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController == self.tabBarController.selectedViewController )
{
 // do something awesome.
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"No match");
}
```

The expression always evaluated false, so I started debugging. I put a breakpoint in the code and hovered my pointer over 'self', which caused the yellow cascading popup where I could see the addresses of both Controllers. The addresses were the same in the popup, which  must be incorrect since the if statement failed. I see the same result in the debugger window.

I added these logging statements later, which revealed that the objects had 2 different addresses.

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController)] );
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(self.tabBarController.selectedViewController)] );
```

Why did the debugger window lie? Specifically, does anyone know what value it displays as its address, and why the controllers would show the same address?

Comment: I rewrote the if statement to the following, but I'm still curious about the debugger.

  if( self.tabBarController.selectedIndex >= 4 && [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] count] > 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this exact same problem, and I'm 90% sure it's related to building for a 2.1 (or possibly 2.X) SDK while using the 3.0 dev tools. In my case, setting the target SDK for 3.0 fixed this issue.
Having your debugger essentially lie to you is frustrating ;)

Comment: Marking this as correct (sorry I didn't do it earlier). I don't see this issue anymore, I guess it was just an SDK and tools bug like you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing EXACTLY the same thing.  Especially with floats.  I switch to 3.1 target and it displays right.  The question is, is the code really working correctly under 2.1 (an NSLog of the variables tells me it is).